# jQuery UI: datepicker - How to add close Button (Image!) on the right top?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to add a close button at the right top.

I don't want to use the close button at the bottom with the button panel.

How can I do that?

I want something like the "X":

[image]

Comment: I guess my main question is why do you want to add a close button?  When a user clicks any where on the page other than the calendar the calendar closes.If you want to specifically add a close button you will have to ".append()" the img/button to the control during runtime and also manipulate the datepicker CSS to cram it into the header.

Comment: Because I have old users who need a "X" to close ;)
That's sad, but if it's the only way, then I will do it at runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can insert the link in the markup and style it as you wish, attaching an onclick handler to it that will call `.datepicker( "hide" )`, a [built-in method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#methods) of datepicker:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var headerPane = $( input )
            .datepicker( "widget" )
            .find( ".ui-datepicker-header" );

            $( "<button>", {
                text: "Close",
                click: function() {
                  $.datepicker.hide();
                }
            }).appendTo( headerPane );
        }, 1 );
    }
});
```

Also, to make space for the close button, you'll probably need to adjust these styles in order to move the 'next month' button over to the left and make space for 'close' button:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next { right:2px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover { right:1px; }
```

**Note:** I've taken the above JS code from [this proof of concept](http://jsbin.com/ofare/edit#source) and adjusted it accordingly. Hasn't tested it though.

Comment: I have added this code and it worked. But when we go to next month. The close button hide. we cant find close button after that. And of course "$.datepicker.hide();" not working.

Answer (score 3):

I kept getting this error:

```
$.datepicker.hide() is not a function
```

via firebug using @dalbaeb's solution. It was right but I had to tweak it a bit to get it to close the datepicker.

This is how I tweaked it and it worked for me:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
beforeShow: function( input ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var headerPane = $( input )
        .datepicker( "widget" )
        .find( ".ui-datepicker-header" );
        $( "<button>", {
            text: "Close",
            click: function() {

             $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();         

            }
        }).appendTo( headerPane );
    }, 1 );
}
});
```

I just replaced:

```
$.datepicker.hide();
```

With this:

```
 $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
```

...and it closes the datepicker now! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

I have done this by styling the `Done` button

First, enable the `showButtonPanel` option then change it's text:

```
$(".calendar").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: '&times;'
});
```

Then hide the `Today` button and style the close button:

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-current {
    display: none;
}
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    color: #cc6a6a;
    font-weight: 600;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-close:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of the button this way:

```
    $("#id_from_date").datepicker({
        closeText: "X",
        showButtonPanel: true,
    });
    $('#id_from_date').click(function() {
        $(this).datepicker("show");
        var button = $(".ui-datepicker-close");
        $(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane").remove();
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").children().first().before(button);
        button.css("margin-left", button.parent().width() - 30 + "px");
    });
```

Hope it helps. If not, let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I moved the buttonpane to the top and then did the rest in CSS.

```
$( "[data-date-picker]" )
  .datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: "X"
  })
  .on('click', function() {
    var datepicker = $('#ui-datepicker-div')
    datepicker.prepend(datepicker.find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane"));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to hide the datepicker:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('hide');
```